# Canvas colors "leaking"

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a program that makes a checkered canvas for you, and you can find it at the bottom of the page.

It looks ok but when you select a large size with a small amount of lines it starts to sort of leak or something. For example, try selecting size twenty with three lines. You'll get what I mean.

If you open the console I `console.log`-ed the value of the number of the color and the color that was being drawn.

Here is the link to the JSfiddle and the function in question:
https://jsfiddle.net/6r05ye2t/

```
function make() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            var linelength = 1;
            var colors = [], inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
            for (var j = 0; j < lines; j++) {
                colors.push(inputs[j].value);
            }
            console.log(size);
            var colornum = 0, shift = 0;
            for (var column = 0; column < size; column++) {
                for (var row = 0; row < size; row++) {
                    if (colornum >= lines) {
                        colornum -= lines;
                    }
                    canvas.fillStyle = colors[colornum];console.log(colornum);console.log(colors[colornum]);
                    colornum++;
                    canvas.fillRect(row*50, column*50, 50, 50);
                }
                shift++;
                colornum = shift;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing as I am not sure what you mean by "Leak"?

Change the render loop as follows

```
for (var column = 0; column < size; column += 1) {
    for (var row = 0; row < size; row += 1) {
        // remove the condition statement
        //if (colornum >= lines) {  // remove
        //  colornum -= lines;      // remove
        //}                         // remove

        // Then to get the values 0, 1, 2, ... (lines-1)
        // use the modulo operator % to get the remainder of colornum divided 
        // by lines. 

        canvas.fillStyle = colors[colornum % lines];
        canvas.fillRect(row * 50, column * 50, 50, 50);
        colornum += 1;
    }
    shift += 1;
    colornum = shift;
}
```

Comment: you can see how it leaks if you go onto the fiddle and try a large size like 20 with a small number. Oh hey... It works!! Thanks!!